# How much of a negative impact do bonyads have on Iran's economy?

Tags: economy, iran, middle-east

[Bonyads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonyad) are charitable trusts that control about 20% of Iran's GDP and have been criticized for being ["a major weakness of Iran's economy"](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/policy/defense-national-security/how-irans-elite-use-islamic-charities-to-control-secret-economic-empires) and providing [inadequate charity to the poor](http://www.payvand.com/news/07/jan/1295.html#_edn7)(Mackey, Sandra Iranians, Persia, Islam, and the soul of a nation, New York: Dutton, c1996 (p.370)). How much of a negative impact do bonyads have on Iran's economy?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think Bonyads are any worse than the 70% of Iran's economy which is state-controlled according to the IMF. (Your link doesn't work for me and it looks like to goes to an UAE website, which I would consider a doubtful source for anything regarding Iran given that they are fighting a proxy war.)

Comment: Added different new links that would be better sources. Also, the reason why I think that is because the current sources talk about how bonyads are corrupt and unprofitable since they -according to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonyad#Criticism) and more reliable sources like the Washington Examiner and the Economist ("Business: A mess; Iranian privatisation", The Economist. London: Jul 21, 2001. Vol. 360, Iss. 8231; pg. 51)- are overstaffed, corrupt, and unprofitable since they control a sizable portion of Iran's economy in spite of these problems.

Comment: Funnily they've been compared with Fannie Mae and Freddie Mac in one (French) paper on the "parastatal sector". https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/37926/1/Soft_Budget_constraint_and_parastatal_sector-oct2011-pdf.pdf

Comment: Keep in mind that Iran follow Islamic banking rules on the immorality of charging interest rates.  While bonyads may or may not be a drag on the economy (I'd never heard of them), this needs placing into the context of a financial system that is likely to have other challenges as well.  Wikipedia entry, badly outdated : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banking_and_insurance_in_Iran.